# Ember select view controller based on content

Tags: ember.js

I currently have a view setup that renders the template depending on the model:

```
<ul>
  {{#each controller.sortedAll}}
    {{view App.ScoreView}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

.

```
App.ScoreView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: function(){
    var item = this.get('context')
    if (item.sort < 8){
        return 'low'
    } else {
      return 'high'
    }
  }.property(),
})
```

I'm struggling with assigning a specific controller for each separate view. The jsbin is: http://jsbin.com/tahag/5/edit

Is it possible to specify the controller in `App.ScoreView` using `controller:`? Or would I be better off trying to set an item controller:

```
{{view App.ScoreView itemController="VAL"}}
```

And pass the `VAL` from the parent controller as a property?

Comment: BTW the high and low controller should be extending the ObjectController.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller is inherited from the current scope (defining itemController on the view won't do anything).  You should do it on the each.

```
{{#each controller.sortedAll itemController='val'}}
    {{view App.ScoreView}}
{{/each}}
```

Then within the view you can do `this.get('controller')...`

Also you can do an if statement and do `{{render 'high' this}}` if you want to have different types of controllers on each item.

```
{{#each controller.sortedAll}}
   {{#if isBlue}}
      {{render 'blue' this}}
   {{/if}}
   {{#if isGreen}}
      {{render 'green' this}}
   {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

### Personal recommendations:

To avoid making your template super convoluted I would just use a single controller.

```
 {{#each controller.sortedAll itemController='score'}}
   {{input value=sort}}
   {{view App.ScoreView}}
 {{/each}}
```

Add what the computed property is dependent on in order for it to automagically update:

```
App.ScoreView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: function(){
    var sort = this.get('controller.sort');
    if (sort < 8){
      return 'low';
    } else {
      return 'high';
    }
  }.property('controller.sort'),
});
```

Take advantage of the `computed` helpers

```
App.ScoreController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isVeryHigh: Em.computed.gt('sort', 20),
  isVeryLow: Em.computed.lt('sort', 4)
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/sidebozi/1/edit

Comment: So if I wanted to have different views, and a specific controller for each view I should have an if statement for each render, ie: `{{render 'high'}}` and another if statement for `{{render 'low'}}`?

Comment: If you want to have different controller, yes.  Honestly that feels like a lot of overhead though, I added some recommendations above